# How Do I Detect If a Pixel in a Bitmap Is Black

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm making a program and I need to know how to see if a pixel in a bitmap image is very dark or black. Big thanks if you can help.

```
//need help
if (_Bitmap.GetPixel(c, d, Color.FromArgb(255) == 255)) mouse_event((int)Test.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
//need help
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get color of a pixel you should use `GetPixel` method.
You can use [GetBrightness](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.getbrightness(v=vs.110).aspx) method of `Color` class to get a brightness and check "how dark" is the color.
Brightness equals to 0 for pure black, and maximum value is 1.

So you can compare a brightness with some threshold for example 0.02.

```
if (_Bitmap.GetPixel(c,d).GetBrightness() < 0.02) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is either very simple or deceptively complex.

Whether a pixel is black or not depends on the colour model the pixel is expressed in. In RGB a black pixel is expressed by the integer 0. Other colour models have other representations for black. In each case it is very straight forward to figure out whether a pixel is pure black.
However you also ask whether a pixel is very, very dark, and that may be tricky.

If you have a clear threshold for darkness (say the intensity/luminescence is less than 10%) then the answer is also straight forward. 
This is easier in colour models with a separate intensity component but in RGB you might make due with the following approximation `redComponent < 25 && greenComponent < 25 && blueComponent < 25`

However if you ask whether a pixel is **perceived as dark**, then we thread into more complex territory. To determine whether a pixel is perceived as dark you'll need to take into consideration the values of adjacent pixels and figure out whether a darkening gradient exists. Some pixel shades will look bright if they are near the local intensity maximum, but will look dark if they are near the local intensity minimum (see [checker shadow illusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checker_shadow_illusion) for a well known example). Likewise a very dark vary narrow line adjacent a bright object may look as the edge of object and not as a dark element in the image.